# Regular expression for single line java comments

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expression, Am finding empty IF statements by using this `if[\\s]*\\([^\\)]*\\)[\\s]*\\{((/\\*(.|[\\r\\n])*?\\*/)|\\s)*\\}` and its works fine fine multi line comments with empty statements but not find single line comments. It find the below scenarios

```
if (true) {

        /*
         * fsdsddgd ddgdgdfg gdfgdgdfg gdfgdfg fgdfgfg
         */

        /*
         * fsdsddgd ddgdgdfg gdfgdgdfg gdfgdfg fgdfgfg
         */
    }

if (true) {


    }
```

Not find the below scenarios

```
if (true) {
        // kavi
        // kamal
        // kamal
    }

    if (true) {
        // kavi
    }
```

please give me valuable solutions for this.

Comment: That's a job for your IDE. Which IDE are you using? Eclipse: `Compiler / Errors / Empty`

Comment: Note that you can't make it work if you have nested parenthesis in your condition.

Comment: am not using eclipse IDE. but i wrote a sample program for regular exp practice but its seems nightmare.

Comment: i need to find find single comments also. So please guide me in regexp. Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to parse a language without a proper grammar and parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not A Great Idea, but if you have to...**

As you can see in the comments I'm not terribly fond of the idea, but since you asked for it, this will work with your input (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fD8vD3)):

```
if\s*\([^\{]*\{(?:[ \t]*//.*)?[ \t]*(?:[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?)*[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?}
```

- The `if\s*\([^\{]*\{` gets us to the opening brace
- The `(?:[ \t]*//.*)?[ \t]*` gets us to the end of the line, matching an optional comment along the way
- The `(?:[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?)*` matches a series of lines with optional comments
- The `[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?}` gets us to the final brace.

Tokens need to be properly escaped, so try this code:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("if\\s*\\([^\\{]*\\{(?:[ \t]*//.*)?[ \t]*(?:[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?)*[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?}");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**else if**

In the comments you say you may not want `else if`

In that case, use this:

```
(?<!else )if\s*\([^\{]*\{(?:[ \t]*//.*)?[ \t]*(?:[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?)*[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?
```

In code:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<!else )if\\s*\\([^\\{]*\\{(?:[ \t]*//.*)?[ \t]*(?:[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?)*[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: The class shortcut `\h` isn't available in Java -> `[^\S\r\n]` or `[ \t]` perhaps.

Comment: Are you sure? RB is happy with it. Let me double-check.

Comment: regexplanet is not happy at all. It seems to be available for Java 8 only.

Comment: Hi, its not working in java code. getting this " Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 19
if\s*\([^\{]*\{(?:\h*//.*)?\h*(?:[\r\n]*\h*(?://.*)?)*[\r\n]*\h*(?://.*)?}" while matching this.

Comment: It must be the `\h`, as Caz suggested. Edited the answer, ca you try the new regex? `if\s*\([^\{]*\{(?:[ \t]*//.*)?[ \t]*(?:[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?)*[\r\n]*[ \t]*(?://.*)?}` Will post Java code in a moment.

Comment: Hey, added Java code, have a look. Maybe a problem with the `\`, but the code should work. :)

Comment: it works fine but it removes else if too. I want to check if statements only. else if(true) {// kavi } the string also find. So i want to find exact match. please sorry for this.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte FYI `\h` is supported in Java 8 (the platform I was testing against) but not Java 7. :) [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: And also find exactly else if statements only. please kindly help me.

Comment: Hi! 1. First, look at the bottom of the answer. I added a regex for an `if` that is not `else if`. 2. If you want `else if` exactly, just add `else ` in front of the `if` in the first regex. If the answer is correct, please consider clicking the checkmark on the left to accept it, that's how reputation works on this site. Thanks!

Comment: If i want else exaclty then what i want to do?. Thanks in advance. Am very new to regular expression. i can create simple but not able to create complex expression. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zx81: I finally understood what 'Caz' means. :)

Comment: If you want something else just tell me. Is it working now, or still needs tweaking?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm sure you know it's with no disrespect... It's just that I never seem to manage to remember where the `i` and the `y` goes... :)

Comment: @user3758887 That's terrific, glad to hear it, thanks! See you next time. :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Am trying to find empty conditional statements using regular expression. Almost all conditions are satisfied. Thanks a lot. I have to learn regular expression. If you know good resource for this means. please do let me share the link. Thanks a lot .....

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I am finding in try block the string logger.error(".......") exists, so please provide for regular expression...