# Remove all comments & block comments from all .java files in eclipse

Tags: java

I'm working on a big source (more than 50.000 java files) and i want to remove all comments Ex. `// This is for iterate over list`  and block i think they are called comments that starts with `/**` and ends with `*/` to clean up my source.

Is there any function or plugin in eclipse that does this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [eclipse - Remove All Comments in Java Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326900/21252090)

Comment: Tried, didn't work.

Comment: The quick/one-off solution would be a regex replace for the specific things you want to eliminate (e.g. `//comments` and `/* comments */`), being careful about multiline patterns. The robust solution would likely be a Java parser/grammar to manually exclude comment tokens.

Answer (score 0):

***You might want to have a backup of your files before doing this, as it is good practice if you ever need to revert back to the previous changes.***

There is indeed an option in Eclipse that lets you do that. It is simply the find/replace dialog. Start by pressing "Ctrl + F" when working in your project. Then, check the "Regular expression" option. This will let you use regular expressions to find the lines that match your description.

To remove single line comments, simply use the following in the "find" field: //.*
then, press the "Replace all" button. Every single-line comments should disappear.

To remove block comments, use the following in the "find" field:
/*(?:.|\n|\r\n)*?*/
then, "Replace all" button.

You might want to specify the scope of your search, as you might want to limit the search by selecting appropriate directories, packages etc.